# Ruby methods equivalent of "if a in list" in python?

Tags: python, ruby, syntax

In python I can use this to check if the element in list `a`:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> 5 in a
True
>>> 16 in a
False
```

How this can be done in Ruby?

Comment: Later, similar question, not worded in terms of Python, with more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343861/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-my-array-includes-an-object

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `include?()` method:

```
(1..10).include?(5) #=>true
(1..10).include?(16) #=>false
```

EDIT:
`(1..10)` is [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html) in Ruby , in the case you want an Array(list) :

```
(1..10).to_a #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: So this is like index() methods that return nil(false) or index(true)?

Comment: Index works only on Array but not on Range. !(1..10).to_a.index(5).nil? equals (1..10).include?(5). Obviously, latter is better.

Answer (score 10):

Range has the === method, which checks whether the argument is part of the range.

You use it like this:

```
(1..10) === 5  #=> true
(1..10) === 15 #=> false
```

or as you wrote it:

```
a= (1..10)
a === 5  #=> true
a === 16 #=> false
```

You must be sure the values of the range and the value you are testing are of compatible type, otherwise an Exception will be thrown.

```
(2.718..3.141) === 3 #=> true
(23..42) === "foo"   # raises exception
```

- This is done in O(1), as Range#===(value) only compares value with Range#first and Range#last.
- If you first call Range#to_a and then Array#include?, it runs in O(n), as Range#to_a, needs to fill an array with n elements, and Array#include? needs to search through the n elements again.

If you want to see the difference, open irb and type:

```
(1..10**9) === 5            #=> true
(1..10**9).to_a.include?(5) # wait some time until your computer is out of ram and freezess
```

Comment: This only applies to ranges, the OP asked for lists (and used range only as an example of a list)

Comment: he wrote list list but used a Range in his example, so I think he want's a range. It seems as there is no native way in Python to create a range which is not a list. (but I must point out, I am no python expert, so my assumption may be wrong)

Comment: In python, there's no range type. So range(10) is to generated [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] list that's (0..9) in ruby (for precisely, it's xrange(10) that's generator which yield value only when you want it).

For this case, I didn't notice which type is it before because I used "gets.split.each". Btw, this's a very nice answer!