# How do I check to see if my array includes an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array `@horses = []` that I fill with some random horses.

How can I check if my `@horses` array includes a horse that is already included (exists) in it?

I tried something like:

```
@suggested_horses = []
  @suggested_horses << Horse.find(:first,:offset=>rand(Horse.count))
  while @suggested_horses.length < 8
    horse = Horse.find(:first,:offset=>rand(Horse.count))
    unless @suggested_horses.exists?(horse.id)
       @suggested_horses<< horse
    end
  end
```

I also tried with `include?` but I saw it was for strings only. With `exists?` I get the following error:

```
undefined method `exists?' for #<Array:0xc11c0b8>
```

So the question is how can I check if my array already has a "horse" included so that I don't fill it with the same horse?

Comment: This question would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529986/ruby-methods-equivalent-of-if-a-in-list-in-python if that question weren't worded in terms of Python.

Comment: I'm curious - how it that useful to know?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Arrays in Ruby don't have `exists?` method, but they have an [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method [as described in the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F).
Something like

```
unless @suggested_horses.include?(horse)
   @suggested_horses << horse
end
```

should work out of box.

Comment: this could be bad, since include? will scan entire array and is order of n O(n)

Comment: It's linear in time, it goes through the list once over each item. There isn't any point in nitpicking about performance though. It's such a simple case. If you care about speedy lookup use either [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html) or [`Set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) from `std-lib`.

Comment: Inversely:

unless horse.in?(@suggested_horses)
   @suggested_horses << horse
end

Comment: @Kush: Agreed, O(n) isn't ideal. However, if we short-circuit, the avg case is still O(n) ;)  Finally, we chose to write in Ruby (of all the langs...)

Answer (score 32):

If you want to check if an object is within in array by checking an attribute on the object, you can use [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) and pass a block that evaluates to true or false:

```
unless @suggested_horses.any? {|h| h.id == horse.id }
  @suggested_horses << horse
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`#include?` should work, it works for [general objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002203), not only strings. Your problem in example code is this test:

```
unless @suggested_horses.exists?(horse.id)
  @suggested_horses<< horse
end
```

(even assuming using `#include?`). You try to search for specific object, not for id. So it should be like this:

```
unless @suggested_horses.include?(horse)
  @suggested_horses << horse
end
```

ActiveRecord has [redefined](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001870) comparision operator for objects to take a look only for its state (new/created) and id

Answer (score 3):

Why not do it simply by picking eight different numbers from `0` to `Horse.count` and use that to get your horses?

```
offsets = (0...Horse.count).to_a.sample(8)
@suggested_horses = offsets.map{|i| Horse.first(:offset => i) }
```

This has the added advantage that it won't cause an infinite loop if you happen to have less than 8 horses in your database.

*Note:* `Array#sample` is new to 1.9 (and coming in 1.8.8), so either upgrade your Ruby, `require 'backports'` or use something like `shuffle.first(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

> So the question is how can I check if my array already has a "horse" included so that I don't fill it with the same horse?

While the answers are concerned with looking through the array to see if a particular string or object exists, that's really going about it wrong, because, as the array gets larger, the search will take longer.

Instead, use either a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html), or a [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). Both only allow a single instance of a particular element. Set will behave closer to an Array but only allows a single instance. This is a more preemptive approach which avoids duplication because of the nature of the container.

```
hash = {}
hash['a'] = nil
hash['b'] = nil
hash # => {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil}
hash['a'] = nil
hash # => {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil}

require 'set'
ary = [].to_set
ary << 'a'
ary << 'b'
ary # => #<Set: {"a", "b"}>
ary << 'a'
ary # => #<Set: {"a", "b"}>
```

Hash uses name/value pairs, which means the values won't be of any real use, but there seems to be a little bit of extra speed using a Hash, based on some tests.

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

ALPHABET = ('a' .. 'z').to_a
N = 100_000
Benchmark.bm(5) do |x|
  x.report('Hash') { 
    N.times {
      h = {}
      ALPHABET.each { |i|
        h[i] = nil
      }
    }
  }

  x.report('Array') {
    N.times {
      a = Set.new
      ALPHABET.each { |i|
        a << i
      }
    }
  }
end
```

Which outputs:

```
            user     system      total        real
Hash    8.140000   0.130000   8.270000 (  8.279462)
Array  10.680000   0.120000  10.800000 ( 10.813385)
```

Answer (score 1):

Array's `include?`method accepts any object, not just a string. This should work:

```
@suggested_horses = [] 
@suggested_horses << Horse.first(:offset => rand(Horse.count)) 
while @suggested_horses.length < 8 
  horse = Horse.first(:offset => rand(Horse.count)) 
  @suggested_horses << horse unless @suggested_horses.include?(horse)
end
```

- [`Array#include?` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002203)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `horses.include? new_horse` is `new_horse.in? horses`.

I don't think there's much (any?) difference under the hood, but sometimes it reads better that way. Particularly if you want the first term to explain a bit more of what is going on before reading the entire statement. For example, this:

```
[403, 404, 503].include? http_status
```

...is not as readable as:

```
http_status.in? [403, 404, 503]
```