# Ruby element present in array or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check if my array includes an object - rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343861/how-to-check-if-my-array-includes-an-object-rails)

I have array

```
array['one', 'two', 'three']
```

How i find that 'two' element present in array.

Is any method in ruby which can find this?

Thanks

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`array.include?('two')` returns `true` or `false`

Answer (score 11):

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002203

```
array.include?('two')
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use:

```
array.index('two')
```

will return index of object if present else will return nil.