# ruby way of checking if an object is in an array

Tags: ruby

I come from the Java world so I was shocked to discover that arrays (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) does not hava a method `contains(object)` returning `bool`.

What is the good way - the Ruby way - of doing that ?

Comment: You'll find that most methods are named differently. :)

Comment: You might actually want to read documentation before posting questions like this, otherwise you end up looking stupid and/or lazy.  Especially if you are going to link to the documentation in the question.

Comment: I ctrl-fed the page with 'contains', 'bool' (to get methods by return type), 'has' ... no luck. Sorry if I disturbed you in your peace Paul Leader.

Comment: If that's all you did before posting to SO then it makes you look lazy (hence why your question is rated 0).  I'm just suggesting that you might learn rather more if you actually read the docs. In the time it takes to post a question here you could have read most of the Array class documentation, certainly the list of methods right at the top.  If I started coding in Java I would not expect every class method to be called the same, and to be able to just ctrl-f for a couple of terms and assume that finding nothing indicates no such thing exists and then be "shocked" at the absence.

Comment: Paul: Relax. The answers are often obvious; that doesn't mean we're idiots.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to check if my array includes an object - rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343861/how-to-check-if-my-array-includes-an-object-rails)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check to see if my array includes an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343861/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-my-array-includes-an-object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**array.include?(obj) → true or false**

Returns true if the given object is present in self (that is, if any object == anObject), false otherwise.

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.include?("b")   #=> true
a.include?("z")   #=> false
```

This, from the [Array class documentation](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000441):

Answer (score 6):

```
[1,2,3].include? 2
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [1,2,3].include? 3
 => true 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [1,2,3].include? 33
 => false
```

Comment: did everybody read the question wrong at first... i thought it was "to check if an object is an array"

Comment: Yep, so did I.  Weird, the title is perfectly correct, but my brain skipped the "in".

Comment: could it be while we were typing the answer, the author changed the question.... so question has timestamp which is earlier than our answers, so won't show revision

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Array.index("ITEM")
```

if the result is != de nil the element exists.

Regards.