# Rails Check if User Id is in Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to build a condition based on wether or not a "user" is a "member". Basically I need a way of checking if the current_user.id matches any of the user_id of any members. The non-working code I have right now is:

```
<% if current_user = @page.members %>
  you can view this content.
<% end %>
```

I'm looking for something along the lines of: "If current_user.id exists in the "user_id" of any members."

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if my array includes an object - rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343861/how-to-check-if-my-array-includes-an-object-rails)

Comment: Are you using devise? If so you could use the signed_in? helper. Having current_user in devise automatically implies that the user is logged in. If you are not using devise, might I ask why not? It's wonderfully documented, easy to override controllers etc for specific things. Otherwise, I would recommend taking a look at Michael Hartle's tutorials whereby he walks you through a detailed User model including authentication.

Comment: No, this question is different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this, based on the field names in your question:

```
<% if @page.members.map(&:user_id).include? current_user.id %>
  You can view this content
<% end %>
```

Comment: No need to map first, try enumerable#any? @page.members.any?{|m| m.user_id == current_user.id}. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your `@page.members` variable contains an array, you can use the [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method:

```
<% if @page.members.include? current_user %>
  you can view this content.
<% end %>
```

If you're using an array of ids, you will of course need to change the test slightly to look for the current user's id:

```
<% if @page.members.include? current_user.id %>
  you can view this content.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@member_ids = @page.members.map{|m| m.id()}
```

then check for the condition as below

```
@memeber_ids.include? current_user.id()
```

Answer (score 0):

Has said before `include?` should do the thing.

I'm just answering to tell you about a gem called **[CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)**, that gives you easy access for authorization "helpers".

Why you should use **CanCan** instead of doing what you are actually doing?

1. Don't reinventing the weel most of the times it's a goob practice.
2. You are placing business logic on the view (bad practice).
3. CanCan most likely has been developed thinking on security, and all the best practices in mind.
4. You save some developing hours.

Sorry if I repeated myself.