# Do JavaScript arrays have an equivalent of Python’s “if a in list”?

Tags: javascript, python

If I have a list in Python, I can check whether a given value is in it using the `in` operator:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> 'a' in my_list
True

>>> 'd' in my_list
False
```

If I have an array in JavaScript, e.g.

```
var my_array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Can I check whether a value is in it in a similar way to Python’s `in` operator, or do I need to loop through the array?

Comment: In other words, I’m asking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529986/ruby-methods-equivalent-of-if-a-in-list-in-python), but for JavaScript instead of Ruby.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Comment: @6502: ah, that’s the stuff. Write that up into an answer and the points are yours.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)  qeustion.

Comment: @mouad: great spot — I’m actually using underscore.js, which the top answer to that question mentions, so I might use their function for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var my_array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
alert(my_array.indexOf('b'));
alert(my_array.indexOf('dd'));
```

if element not found, you will receive **-1**

Comment: In modern browser, yes, but older internet explorers does not support it. Here is a question about it (and the workaround):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc

Comment: what if searched item exists more than one in an array ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz indexOf returns the first occurrence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 31):

Since ES7, it is recommended to use `includes()` instead of the clunky `indexOf()`.

```
var my_array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

my_array.includes('a');  // true

my_array.includes('dd'); // false
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var IN = function(ls, val){
    return ls.indexOf(val) != -1;
}

var my_array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
IN(my_array, 'a');
```

Answer (score 1):

The most current way with ES7 would be the following:

```
let myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

console.log(myArray.includes('a'))
```

This will return `true` or `false`.